# Prove that $ \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{2}{3!} + \frac{3}{4!}+\cdots + \frac{n}{(n+1)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ for $n\in \mathbb N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I want to prove that if $n \in \mathbb N$ then $$\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{2}{3!} + \frac{3}{4!}+ \cdots+ \frac{n}{(n+1)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}.$$

I think I am stuck on two fronts. First, I don't know how to express the leading terms on the left hand side before the $\dfrac{n}{(n+1)!}$ (or if doing so is even necessary to solve the problem). I am also assuming that the right high side should initially be expressed $1 - \dfrac{1}{(n+2)!}$. But where to go from there.

I'm actually not sure if I'm even thinking about it the right way.

Comment: $$\frac{n-1}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac 1 {n!}$$

Comment: induction works

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{n}{(n+1)!} = \dfrac{1}{n!} - \dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}$

Comment: Telescoping Series(+1)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  If, for somespecific $n$, we have
$$\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{2}{3!} + \frac{3}{4!}+ \cdots+ \frac{n}{(n+1)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\ ,$$
then
$$\eqalign{\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+\frac{3}{4!}+\cdots+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}
  &=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}\cr
  &=1-\frac{n+2}{(n+2)!}+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}\cr
  &=1-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}\ .\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

We'll use induction to prove this

given statement is true for $n=1$

then we assume that it's true for $n=k$
$$\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{2}{3!} + \frac{3}{4!}+ \cdots+ \frac{k}{(k+1)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$
and then  by adding $\dfrac{k+1}{(k+2)!}$ on both sides we get 
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{2}{3!} + \frac{3}{4!}+ \cdots+ \frac{k}{(k+1)!} +\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}&= 1 - \frac{1}{(k+1)!}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}\\
&=1 - \frac{k+2}{(k+2)!}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}\\
&=1 +\frac{k+1-k-2}{(k+2)!}\\
&=1-\frac{1}{(k+2)!}\end{align}$$
it's also true for $n=k+1$
And then using Proncipal of mathematical induction...

Answer (score 0):

**Induction**.

1. **Base**. $n = 1: \frac{1}{2!} = 1 - \frac{1}{2!}$.
2. **Step**. $n = m$ $-$ true. Let's prove for $m + 1$:
   $$
   \frac{1}{2!} + \dots + \frac{m}{(m+1)!} + \frac{m+1}{(m+2)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(m+1)!} = 1 - \frac{m+2}{(m+2)!} + \frac{m+1}{(m+2)!} =
   $$
   $$
   = 1 - \frac{1}{(m+2)!}
   $$